# No adapter for handler : The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

We are migrating from spring 4.x to spring 5.2.13 version. In spring 4 this was working but in spring 5.x we are getting the below error for dispatcher servlet

> javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler : The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler
> at

Can anyone help me , what i am missing here?
I am migrating from spring 4.x to spring 5.2.13

Comment: what about formatting your question to make it readable?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, i did formatted my question again

Answer (score 1):

change the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
```

to this:

```
@Controller
```

i.e. Remove the `@RequestMapping` annotation from the class;
it provides no value.

Comment: I tried removing the @RequestMapping but still getting error

Answer (score 1):

This can happens when there is root URL path ("/") in a Spring MVC controller.

In one of the controllers add a @GetMapping("/")

Ex :

```
@RestController("/")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcomeUser() {
        return "<h1> Welcome</h1>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify a mapping for `@RequestMapping` like `@RequestMapping('/')`

Comment: I did try that , but that was not useful still getting this error

Comment: @nandanpandey the error is somewhere else then

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by using mvc:annotation-driven/ in dispatcher xml.

AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter is removed from Spring 5. So when migrating from Spring 4.x to Spring 5.2.13 I was getting the Adaptor issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both:

@RestController /or @Controller
@RequestMapping("your path")